# Run a task repeatedly after some interval in Windows Azure

Tags: c#-4.0, azure, azure-sql-database

I have a task (couple of C# functions) that updates the DB after every interval. How do I achieve this on Windows Azure (assuming after deployment the DB would also move to SQL Azure)

Comment: Great article on building a task scheduler: [link](http://blog.smarx.com/posts/building-a-task-scheduler-in-windows-azure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can develop and deploy a [Windows Azure Compute Worker Role](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg432976.aspx). This would be the right tool for long running and background operations hosted in Azure. Depending on what your task is doing (how CPU intensive it is) you could choose a very small role size to minimize cost.

You could probably also put such a task in a preexisting web or worker role (but that might not be a clean solution depending on what your task is doing and how reliably it should run).

Answer (score 2):

There's several options:
- use a 3rd party job scheduler to initiate the process remotely
- deploy a single "worker instance" that uses the task schedule built into Server 2008 to schedule the processes (this will require statup tasks)
- deploy a timer process as part of another role, just make sure you put in a traffic cop or singleton style pattern to prevent multiple instances rom simultaneously trying to execute the same process.